# Uploading folders to IPFS from command line returns hash but folder doesn't exist on network

Tags: command, ipfs, ipfs-http-client, ipfs-cli

I am trying to upload a folder to IPFS using the command line. It always executes and returns the hash using

```
ipfs add folder --recursive
```

But when I try to view the folder it just keeps loading searching for the folder. When I check the network the folder doesn't exist.

```
ipfs.io/ipfs/{FOLDER HASH}
```

Or I try and call the file explicitly

```
 ipfs.io/ipfs/{FOLDER HASH}/video.mp4
```

Every once and a while the hash exist on the network and I can view the directory, but most of the time it doesn't. Im not sure whats happening here. Is it because of a lack of peers or something? I set IPFS on my web server (apache), I can upload single files and they usually work if its a small txt file or something or image. Can anyone explain why this is or how to get around it?

Ive tried -

```
ipfs pin add folder --recursive
```

And

```
ipfs get {HASH}
```

Which returns "saving {HASH}".. But still cant view the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the user group that was uploading to IPFS wasnt configured to use IPFS. Since I was on apache I had to allow all user groups and now it all works.